# Merge two arrays in JavaScript (ES5 or below)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5

I have 2 arrays that I need to merge in a particular order in javascript.
Here is the sample..

```
var alphabets = [[["a"], ["b"]], ["c"], ["d"], [["e"], ["f"]]];
var numbers   = [[["1"], ["2"]], ["3"], ["4"], [["5"], ["6"]]];

var result    = [[["a", "1"], ["b", "2"]], ["c", "3"], ["d", "4"], [["e", "5"], ["f", "6"]]];
```

Need help here..

here is what I have tried so far

```
var res = [];

var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  res.push(alphabets[i].concat(numbers[i]));
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try to figure it out first, do the research on how to do it, then show what you've tried and what you've discovered.

Comment: updated my question, please review @justDan

Comment: have a look now, @EmielZuurbier, my code is working for single element arrays, but not for array inside array

Comment: Look for [recursion](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/quick-intro-to-recursion/) instead of a simple for loop.... I made a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/VwPjXRL?editors=0012) for you to check. ;)

Comment: thanks a lot!!! you can post this code as answer :D @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: If it gets reopened... Sure ;)

Comment: also you can upvote my question, as it is In bad shape right now :( @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: the answer was just mindblowing to me.. WOW!!!, I just can't thank you enough for that!!! @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, reopened

Comment: yeah, add your ans @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this quite fun "array merging" challenge... (I assume and hope this is a "minimal" example of something more complex). You definitely need a **recursive function**.

A simple `for` loop is not enought to make sure to loop throught any deep level of the arrays without loosing yourself in a mess of duplicate code lines.

---

**Warning**: the logic below ONLY works with two perfectly matching arrays, from the structure point of view.

What is a recursive function by the way? : [freeCodeCamp tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/quick-intro-to-recursion/) ← Best short example I know.

---

So here is the CodePen demo I made for you in a couple minutes... I already knew about recursion and when to use it. But that is a wonderful example, so thanks to your question.

```js
var alphabets = [[["a"], ["b"]], ["c"], ["d"], [["e"], ["f"]]];
var numbers   = [[["1"], ["2"]], ["3"], ["4"], [["5"], ["6"]]];

// Expected result
var expected  = [[["a", "1"], ["b", "2"]], ["c", "3"], ["d", "4"], [["e", "5"], ["f", "6"]]];

// A merging function
let merge = (arr1, arr2) => {
  
  return arr1.map((item, index) =>{
    
    // if the item contains arrays
    // do another recursion
    if (Array.isArray(item[0])){
      return merge(item, arr2[index])  // a recursion is a function calling itself.
    }
    
    // Otherwize, return a "merged" array
    return [item[0], arr2[index][0]]
  })
                         
}

let result = merge(alphabets, numbers)

console.log("Result:\n", JSON.stringify(result))
console.log("Expected:\n", JSON.stringify(expected))
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/VwPjXRL?editors=0012)

The only condition in that recursion is the `string` test... You may need more tests on your arrays. Be careful about any infinite loop... Causing a *stack overflow*!!! Have fun coding!

Comment: Why do you test for string instead of array? `Array.isArray(item[0])`

Comment: Good point @vanowm ;) I edited... Thanks.